# How to add multiple forms Joomla 2.5 component

Tags: joomla2.5, custom-component

I am developing a joomla website which required some custom component to integrate manage portfolio, user profile etc. We downloaded one of the hello_world MVC component for joomla 2.5[http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction]  and did necessary customization. First component worked well. But now we need a new component that is having multiple forms required to integrate.
Eg: Store types for one form, store details for another form, manage country/ state by another form.
In the default component having option for manage one form [add/edit/delete/view]. Here I tried to modify/replicate but I failed. 
Can anyone suggest the architecture/ sample code to manage multiple forms [Add/edit/delete/view] in joomla 2.5 component creation.
Any help will be apreciate?

Comment: I think you mean different entities? If so, the you might need to create for each of this entity own model/view/controller. Just look at Joomla's com_content component. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/2.5.x/components/com_content

Comment: You may want to look at something like http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/. This tool can help you layout the custom component and in the end generates the code that you can tweak but it gives a good base to learn from.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Actually I mean something different, I want to use multiple forms in same model/view using Joomla 2.5 MVC? Can any one suggest a method for this or any tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing You're speaking of forms stored in the model/forms folder... You should try to override the getForm() function in your model, to call the right form. You should pass a 'layout' when calling the page and then get it in the model constructor.

May be so:

```
class YourComponentModelYourModel extends JModelAdmin{

           public function __construct($config = array()){
                switch(JRequest::getVar('layout')){
                        case 'firstlayout' : $this->form='firstform';
                        break;
                        case 'secondlayout' : $this->form='secondform';
                        break;
                        default : $this->form='defaultform';
                        }
             parent::__construct($config);
             }
```

...

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) 
    {
        // Get the form.
        $form = $this->loadForm('com_yourcomponent.'.$this->form,$this->form,
                                array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

        if (empty($form)){return false;}
        return $form;
    }
```

You must put a layout for each form in the views/YourView/tmpl folder and the form declaration must call the layout also :

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&layout=firstlayout&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>"
      method="post" name="adminForm" id="draw-form">
```